# CSS/SCSS error: Mismatched property value for "min-width: min(280px, calc(100vw - 1em));"

Tags: css, sass, min

I'm trying to use the CSS `min` function to help with a responsive layout. What I'm doing doesn't look that different from other examples I've seen of using `min`.

`min-width: min(280px, calc(100vw - 1em));`

[image: SCSS error message]

One potential problem from what I've found looking for answers so far is that SCSS (and Sass) have their own min/max functions which are different from CSS, and that can sometimes be a source of conflict. This isn't a situation where their should be any conflict, however, because I'm not trying to use any SCSS variables or other SCSS special feature as the same time.

I even tried much simpler expressions, like `min(10px, 1em)`, and I get the same error. I've tried assigning a simpler expression to a different CSS property, like `width` instead of `min-width`. Still the error persists as long as I try to use `min` in any way.

Comment: [Browser compatibility: only Safari 11.1+](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min#Browser_compatibility

Comment: Thanks! Somehow it didn't leap out at me that this function had so little support.